# What is the max size of type "SQLITE3_INTEGER"?

Tags: php, sqlite

As mentioned in https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html :

> INTEGER: The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

The problem is that the statement below gives the desired result as the ***bound*** values are comparatively smaller (e.g, $roll_no = 1111111111), however, the execution of statement fetches no result when the bound value is bigger(e.g, $roll_no =3333333333) whereas the SQLite table already holds record with that bigger value.

Is it because the parameter value is truncated or any other reason? What is to be done to get rid of it?

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("select sname,reg_no from student where roll_no=:roll_no");

$stmt1->bindParam(':roll_no', $roll_no, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
```

Comment: What's your `PHP_INT_MAX`?

Comment: May be it is 2147483647, as I am using 32 bit system,can it be changed to unsigned and if so, will changing solve my problem?

Comment: PHP only supports signed integers. So, no.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Then is it good to change it to SQLITE3_TEXT without altering the data type in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the PDO driver of PHP:
https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=SQLITE_INTEGER&unscoped_q=SQLITE_INTEGER

```
#if LONG_MAX <= 2147483647
            if (val > ZEND_LONG_MAX || val < ZEND_LONG_MIN) {
                ZVAL_STRINGL(data, (char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, column), sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, column));
```

It supports returning larger integers, but only as strings.

There's no way to have `3333333333` as native integer on PHPs end (32-bit versions). Such it would become a float before it even reaches SQLite.

What you should do is not trying to bind it as integer. Use a string. SQL does type casting of its own. You could likely keep the column as INTEGER on SQLites end even. It's only PHP you have to work around. Or you know, do the overdue upgrade.